# Churchill Solitaire

Tags: solitaire

I can't get close to winning in Churchill Solitaire. I must be doing something wrong.

1. Do the Devils Six have to be taken in order to the eight piles to the right? Or from anywhere within the six?
2. In the vertical columns, if you have K Q J 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3, are you permitted to take from the middle of the column , say 10 through six,  and transfer to another column?

Comment: Your second question here you've asked previously here https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/51059/churchill-solitaire-moving-cards-on-playing-field which has a link to the rules which cover that.

Comment: Better to split into 2 separate questions and write a descriptive headline

Answer (score -1):

(1) Yes, the Devil's six are moved in order from right to left. (2) Yes, you can move part of a stack, so if what you describe had, say, a 4 at the top of the column and you had a new column topped by K Q J, I would move it.